# cout not printing string of vector after getline

Tags: c++, ifstream, c++20, cout, getline

I have a .csv file with following contents:

```
1.0,2.0
2.0,3.0
```

Now i want to read this file and print it to the terminal.
I want the output look like this:

```
1.0|2.0|
2.0|3.0|
```

But all i get is:

```
|
|
```

When i run the debugger the vector contains the correct data but it just wont print it.

Vector array while cout (debugger):

```
array = {std::vector<std::vector>}
   [0] = {std::vector<std::basic_string, std::allocator>}
      [0] = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>} "1.0"
      [1] = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>} "2.0\r"
   [1] = {std::vector<std::basic_string, std::allocator>}
      [0] = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>} "2.0"
      [1] = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>} "3.0\r"
```

My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream in("C:\\Users\\freit\\CLionProjects\\Aufgabe2\\data.csv", ios_base::in);

    string line, field;

    vector< vector<string> > array;  // the 2D array
    vector<string> v;                // array of values for one line only

    while ( getline(in,line) )    // get next line in file
    {
        v.clear();
        stringstream ss(line);

        while (getline(ss,field,','))  // break line into comma delimited fields
        {
            v.push_back(field);  // add each field to the 1D array
        }

        array.push_back(v);  // add the 1D array to the 2D array
    }

    // print out what was read in

    for (size_t i=0; i<array.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<array[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            cout.flush();
            cout << array[i][j] << "|"; // (separate fields by |)
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: prints expected output here: https://godbolt.org/z/rT5rPY5Ev (apart from extra trailing `|`)

Comment: the thing is: Even if the contents of the `array[i][j]` are not printed, you should see `||` not just `|` per line. Are you sure you are compiling the code you think you are compiling?

Comment: i am sure. thats why i am so confused...
using clion

Comment: sorry I have to ask again, you really see two lines of `|` and not `||` ? and not a single line with `|` ?

Comment: youre right i should see two of them per line. the debugger iterates correctly. but no i just see one of them

Comment: i should have tried this before, but i will reset my ide and try it again...

Comment: `\r` is a carriage return [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). Could be that you wrote the file in Windows but read it in Linux or vice versa, see here: https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows

Comment: oh wow that actually helped a lot!
i just re-write the data.cls file and now it works as intendet!
the `\r` did all this trouble!
thanks a lot!
edit: i forgot the second `|` in my question

Comment: well actually I didnt do the question a favour with my last comment (shame on me). You did use a debugger, you included expected and actual output and a complete example, ie its a well written question that should get an answer. I just don't understand the details well enough to write one.

Comment: thx, i just wanted to provide all information i could because it is an ridiculous error.
u helped me with your point of view. the `\r` was in my textfile i wanted to read. so `cout` got some problems with it. the `\r` must have been appeared after i accidentally opened the `data.cls` with excel (autosave). resolve: wrote a new `data.cls`. but i just didnt noticed just until you mentioned it!

Comment: i will write this comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is within the `data.cls` i wanted to read.
The debugger shows an `\r` ([escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)) at the end of every line.
This might have appeared after opening `data.cls` with Excel and the autosave ticked.
Problem was solved after writing a new `data.cls` with standard windows texteditor. Got the solution thanks to comments!

Comment: when the answer solved your problem you should accept it :)

Comment: only available in 2 days

Comment: oh really? didnt know about that restriction. Anyhow, glad to help.